# Set language-related environment vars for _all_ processes (not just inside Terminal)

Tags: macos, internationalization, environment-variables

On my somewhat creaky MBP running Yosemite, I find that the POSIX environment variables for controlling the locale (`LANG` and `LC_*`) are properly set inside Terminal windows...

```
$ printenv | grep -E '^(LANG|LC_)'
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

... but they are *not* properly set in the environment provided to GUI applications; for instance, inside an [Emacs](https://emacsformacosx.com/) shell window, the above commands print

```
$ printenv | grep -E '^(LANG|LC_)'

$ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

How do I ensure that *every process running on the computer, regardless of how it was started* sees the proper LANG= environment setting?  Bonus points for an answer that doesn't need manual action to stay in sync with the language settings in System Preferences.

(Related questions: [Where does $LANG variable gets set in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21096/where-does-lang-variable-gets-set-in-mac-os-x) indicates that it is Terminal.app that reflects the language settings from System Preferences to the shell's environment.  [Where are system environment variables set in Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57385/where-are-system-environment-variables-set-in-mountain-lion) suggests that the proper way to make manual global environment settings keeps getting changed with each new version of the operating system, yuck.)

Comment: What happens when you start Emacs from the shell? - `open -a Emacs`

Comment: @fd0 That's interesting, the settings are correct if I do it that way. But I want them to be correct if opened from the Dock or whereever.  Also, Emacs is just an example; this potentially affects several other GUI applications I have.

Comment: Then you will need to hack the OS with one of the solutions that fits your current operating systems. If you are willing to change your workflow, the solution I proposed has worked for at least seven versions of the OS.