# Unknown locale, assuming C - Error message in terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line, error

**Note**: The question is not about how to change the locale, or what is the locale. The question is about why is there a locale-based error in `man` in 10.3, but no error in 12.6, even though the locales are identical in both cases.

---

After running `man`, reading a manual entry and closing it, I receive the following error

```
$ man curl                     # The manual opens, I read it, then close
Unknown locale, assuming C
$ man zsh                      # The manual opens, I read it, then close
Unknown locale, assuming C
```

The manual pages work correctly, and can be browsed, but I have no idea where the error comes from, and it is rather annoying.

This is what I obtain when running `locale`

```
$ locale
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

I'm using Ventura 13.0. The same error does not happen in 12.6 even though the `locale` is identical (see below), so I do not think that it is an issue with `locale`, but rather an issue with `man`.

Note that `locale` says

```
   LANG         Used as a substitute for any unset LC_* variable.   \  
If LANG is unset, it will act as if set to "C".  If any of LANG or  \  
LC_* are set to invalid values, locale acts as if they are all unset.
```

so there should be no error, `LANG` should be automatically set to `C`.

EDIT:

Some new insight. I ran the same commands on two computers.

Computer 1 runs 13.0 outputs the error.
This computer has `man` for MacOS 13.0 from January 9 2021.

Computer 2 runs 12.6 and outputs no error.
This computer has `man` version 1.6g from September 19 2005.

The output of the `locale` command is completely identical on both computers, in particular they both have `LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"`.

Could it be a `man` bug?

Comment: Does https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/21107/237 help?

Comment: No. I use iTerm, but neither iTerm nor Terminal change their behaviour when this setting is changed.

Comment: Why are you setting it to "C"?  That's not the default, it should be using one of the UTF-8 locales (depending on your language) unless you changed it somewhere.

Comment: I don't recall ever changing ```locale```. Either this was the default, or I installed some shady brew package that changed these settings. I wiped my system one month ago, and I don't recall doing anything that had to do with changing the locale since reinstalling the OS. The only thing I could think of is having installed TeX, or new keyboards with Ukelele, but I don't see how that could impact the locale settings.

Comment: Reopened. But the question asks "why is there no error on 13.0 but one on 12.6" while the Edit part towards the end mentions "13.0 outputs the error, 12.6 outputs no error". Can you please fix this?

Comment: Having said that: It could be a bug in `man`, it could be a bug in a library, it could be an unknown setting. Easiest way to find out would actually to attach a debugger to the `man` throwing the error, and then just step through it.

Comment: @nohillside It seems that the question was edited by someone. Indeed, I had made a typo, 13.0 = error, 12.6 = no error.

Comment: Uhh, that someone was me. sorry.

Comment: No that is completely fine, I had just seen your comment, but the error was already fixed. I will look into debugging, I never did that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 22):

**Terminal**
Select menu `Terminal` > `Settings...`.
In the window goto `Profiles` and the tab `Advanced`.
At the bottom deselect the option:
**`Set locale environment variables on startup`**
Do this for all the profiles you use.

**iTerm2**
Select menu `iTerm2` > `Settings...`.
In the window goto `Profiles` and the tab `Terminal`.
At the bottom deselect the option:
**`Set locale variables automatically`**
Do this for all the profiles you use.

Still odd that this should be the fix.
According to the Tooltip in iTerm:

> LANG and LC_CTYPE may be set if this is enabled. If you have an unusual setting of country and language then disabling this may help.

So, the root-cause must be the locale settings that got screwed over during the upgrade to 13.0.*. I'm guessing the best fix is to set LANG and LC_CTYPE to something more useful (UTF-8 perhaps, as suggested elsewhere).

Comment: Thanks. This, as mentioned in the above comment, solves the problem. However, I am then unable to write in other languages in the terminal. Not that I would use them in the terminal, but it is annoying when the command prompt outputs hex codes instead of letters when typing. The only difference between selecting and deselecting the "Set locale variables automatically" is that ```LC_CTYPE``` is set to ```UTF-8``` when selected, and ```C``` when deselected. However when setting ```export LANG=en_US.UTF-8``` everything works fine, and there are no errors from ```man```.

Answer (score 6):

I have this issue too and I did some digging. macOS ventura is delivered in this state, it is not due to homebrew or what not. Confirmed in an empty VM. Thought other readers may want to know this.

Disabling the "Set locale environment variables on startup" works
As does setting "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8". Both are comments above.

My guess is the maximum compatibility is achieved with solution #2.

Comment: The ordering of the answers is not the same for all users. If you need to refer to a specific one, please link accordingly. You can use the Share button beneath an answer to get its URL.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that can help resolve the issue:

Open your `.zshrc` file in a text editor, or `.bash_profile` depending on which one you're using.

Add the following lines to the file:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Save and close the file.

Restart your terminal or run `source ~/.zshrc`, or `source ~/.bash_profile` in the terminal to apply the changes.

---

If you want to use everything in English but also want your mother tongue characters to be displayed correctly, you can set the LC_CTYPE environment variable to your mother tongue locale while keeping the other locale-related environment variables set to an English locale such as en_US.UTF-8. This will tell the system to use the English language for most things, but use your mother tongue character set for displaying characters.

---

There is also `LC_ALL` environment variable that can be used to override the values of all other locale-related environment variables. However, setting it can have unintended consequences, as it overrides all other locale settings. Therefore, it’s generally recommended to leave `LC_ALL` unset.

Answer (score 2):

The answer in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/21107/237 is the correct one.

You have this turned off:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! However what's happening is rather the opposite. This setting was turned ON. After turning it off, the error disappears. So this does indeed solve the problem, I must have made a mistake when checking the comment by @mmmmmm . However, the problem, to a certain extent, is not fully solved. The difference in the new locale is that ```LC_CTYPE``` is set to ```UTF-8``` and everything else is the same. Why does this create an error in ```man```?

Comment: This fixes it for Terminal. But not for iTerm2